# Behaviour of parallel running same batch files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, parallel-processing

For fun reasons I wrote a batch-file typing 100 random upper-/lowercase letters whereever I click to. As this turned out to be quite slow I decided to start it from command line with a simple for-loop for more chars in less time:
`for /L %m in (1,1,3) do (start bat.bat)` starting the shell in the folder where the file is located at.

Beeing curious if I really got 300 characters I went to [this website](http://www.charactercountonline.com/) that shows the written characters in realtime and came to an interesting observation: I only get 293 letters (+- 5 or so) and not the expected 300 ones. I assume it is because of the parallel running processes. You can even see that the writing starts in blocks of 3 characters and then suddenly one or two characters are missing and this continues over the whole script duration.

Now the question: Does the parallel running of the same batch-file affect each others process?
Below is the code of the file (and yes I know it is probably done way shorter and more efficient):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

timeout /t 3
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~f0"
for /L %%G in (1,1,100) do (
set /a grkl=!random! %%2
if "x!grkl!"=="x0" (
!SendKeys! "z"
) ELSE (
!SendKeys! "Z"
)
)
exit
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's a bug in SendKeys itself.

I simplified your code to

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ping localhost -n 4 > nul
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~f0"
for /L %%G in (1,1,100) do (
    !SendKeys! "%1"
)
exit
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

And for the test itself I use

```
(for /L %n in (1 1 2) do ( start /b geist.bat %n) ) & set /p var=
```

This works perfect, it outputs 200 characters.
**BUT** if you change `geist.bat %n` to a fixed value like `geist.bat 1`, I got less than 200 characters.
And if I change it to `geist.bat Z` I got `Z` but also lower case `z` characters!
It fails even when I use a fixed string in `WshShell.SendKeys("P");`

If I use only one thread with `for /L %n in (1 1 1)` all works perfect again.

So my conclusion is that the SendKey functionallity is somehow broken.